# RabbitMQ 3.9.10/Erlang 23.3.4.8 RMQ restarting often with disk monitor crashing

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

RMQ (RabbitMQ 3.9.10/Erlang 23.3.4.8) seems to be restarting quite often and logs indicate disk monitor crashing and in turn there are a lot of core dump files created in path /var/lib/rabbitmq that cause disk issues. Are there any configurations that could be wrong here? Any suggestions on how to debug this one

````
2021-11-26 10:53:55.445674+00:00 [info] <0.31883.1> Disk free limit set to 50MB
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1> ** Generic server rabbit_disk_monitor terminating
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1> ** Last message in was update
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1> ** When Server state == {state,"/data/var/mnesia/rabbit@bb774ea67e7c",
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                50000000,29788516352,100,10000,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                #Ref<0.2101168900.3204448257.308>,false,false,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                9,120000}
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1> ** Reason for termination ==
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1> ** {eagain,[{erlang,open_port,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                     [{spawn,"/bin/sh -s unix:cmd"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                      [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide,out]],
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                     []},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>             {os,cmd,2,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,275}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>             {rabbit_disk_monitor,get_disk_free,2,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                  [{file,"rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                   {line,233}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>             {rabbit_disk_monitor,internal_update,1,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                  [{file,"rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                   {line,210}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>             {rabbit_disk_monitor,handle_info,2,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                  [{file,"rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                                   {line,182}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>             {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,689}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>             {gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,765}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}
2021-11-26 10:54:25.475749+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>   crasher:
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     initial call: rabbit_disk_monitor:init/1
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     pid: <0.31883.1>
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     registered_name: rabbit_disk_monitor
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     exception error: eagain
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>       in function  open_port/2
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>          called as open_port({spawn,"/bin/sh -s unix:cmd"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>                              [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide,out])
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>       in call from os:cmd/2 (os.erl, line 275)
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>       in call from rabbit_disk_monitor:get_disk_free/2 (rabbit_disk_monitor.erl, line 233)
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>       in call from rabbit_disk_monitor:internal_update/1 (rabbit_disk_monitor.erl, line 210)
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>       in call from rabbit_disk_monitor:handle_info/2 (rabbit_disk_monitor.erl, line 182)
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>       in call from gen_server:try_dispatch/4 (gen_server.erl, line 689)
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>       in call from gen_server:handle_msg/6 (gen_server.erl, line 765)
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     ancestors: [rabbit_disk_monitor_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.224.0>]
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     message_queue_len: 0
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     messages: []
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     links: [<0.358.0>]
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     dictionary: []
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     trap_exit: false
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     status: running
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     heap_size: 6772
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     stack_size: 28
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>     reductions: 105828
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>   neighbours:
2021-11-26 10:54:25.476488+00:00 [error] <0.31883.1>
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>     supervisor: {local,rabbit_disk_monitor_sup}
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>     errorContext: child_terminated
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>     reason: {eagain,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                 [{erlang,open_port,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      [{spawn,"/bin/sh -s unix:cmd"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                       [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide,out]],
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      []},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                  {os,cmd,2,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,275}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                  {rabbit_disk_monitor,get_disk_free,2,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      [{file,"rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,233}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                  {rabbit_disk_monitor,internal_update,1,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      [{file,"rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,210}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                  {rabbit_disk_monitor,handle_info,2,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      [{file,"rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,182}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                  {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,689}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                  {gen_server,handle_msg,6,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,765}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                  {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                      [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>     offender: [{pid,<0.31883.1>},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                {id,rabbit_disk_monitor},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                {mfargs,{rabbit_disk_monitor,start_link,[50000000]}},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                {restart_type,{transient,1}},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                {shutdown,300000},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.477367+00:00 [error] <0.358.0>                {child_type,worker}]
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1> Free disk space monitor encountered an error (e.g. failed to parse output from OS tools): {{'EXIT',
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                             {eagain,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                              [{erlang,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                open_port,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{spawn,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "/bin/sh -s unix:cmd"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 [binary,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  stderr_to_stdout,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  stream,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  in,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  hide,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  out]],
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                []},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                               {os,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                cmd,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                2,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{file,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "os.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 {line,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  275}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                               {rabbit_disk_monitor,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                get_disk_free,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                2,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{file,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 {line,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  233}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                               {rabbit_disk_monitor,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                enable,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                1,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{file,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 {line,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  309}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                               {rabbit_disk_monitor,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                init,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                1,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{file,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 {line,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  136}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                               {gen_server,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                init_it,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                2,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{file,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "gen_server.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 {line,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  417}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                               {gen_server,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                init_it,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                6,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{file,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "gen_server.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 {line,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  385}]},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                               {proc_lib,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                init_p_do_apply,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                3,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                [{file,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  "proc_lib.erl"},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                 {line,
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>                                                                                                  226}]}]}},
2021-11-26 10:54:25.479258+00:00 [info] <0.31982.1>```
````

Comment: In [the doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2), `eagain` seems to be returned when there are no more OS processes available. Maybe have a look in case you have a lot of zombie processes keeping their PIDs or the process limitation is too low?

Comment: thanks, it was a zombie process issues, adding docker init to the rmq container fixed it